# Send values in PHP variable to JQuery without showing it to user

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to send values in PHP variables to Jquery without using the below representation. Because I don't want to show the values in that array to the users when they click on "View Source".

```
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
```

Comment: Write a script which uses ajax to fetch the json from the server. Keep in mind that it's still possible for them to find this information, no matter how difficult you make it. They can just watch the network requests

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Virtually everything client side can be observed and/or manipulated whereas serverside code cannot. To what purpose the php variables would ultimately be used by jQuery might suggest alternative approaches

Comment: I need to send that php array in one file to another php file through ajax @RamRaider

Comment: you could potentially use php to send the data ( curl ) and avoid the end user ever getting to see the php variables